# Cron Job Pass and Retrieve variables with php

Tags: php, variables, cron, argv

I am running the following cron job:

```
wget -q --spider --timeout=5 --tries=1 "http://www.publicvent.org/wow/kiwi/script.php" index=1
```

In script.php I have:

```
require_once('functions-admin.php');
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$index = $argv[1];
mail('email', 'Test', $index, '');
```

I have also tried unsuccessfully to use:

```
require_once('functions-admin.php');
parse_str(argv[n]);
mail('email', 'Test', $index, '');
```

to no success.

The cron job runs fine, but there is no value in $index.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using $_GET

```
wget -q --spider --timeout=5 --tries=1 "http://www.publicvent.org/wow/kiwi/script.php?index=1"
```

And in your script:

```
require_once('functions-admin.php');
$index = $_GET['index'];
mail('email@localhost', 'Test', $index, '');
```

Regards!

Comment: Please, make sure to add the semicolon that i forget. Regards!